# Customizing JSON serialized response

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am using Json.Net, where I am getting the following result of an object in C#.

```
{"library": [
    {
        "key": "OUTFRMT",
        "description": "Level 1 description",
        "label": "Label 1",
        "value": "Value 1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "OUTFRMT",
        "description": "Level 2 description",
        "label": "Label 2",
        "value": "Value 2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "key": "RQSTYPEFRMT",
        "description": "Level 2 description",
        "label": "Label 2",
        "value": "Value 2",
        "id": 2
    }
]}
```

However,

What I expecting is the following:

```
{
    "library": {
        "new": [
            {
                "label": "New",
                "value": 0,
                "description": "Freshly submitted."
            },
            {
                "label": "New",
                "value": 0,
                "description": "Freshly submitted."
            }
        ],
        "old": [
            {
                "label": "New",
                "value": 0,
                "description": "Freshly submitted."
            },
            {
                "label": "New",
                "value": 0,
                "description": "Freshly submitted."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can change the Class structure and even I do, I don't know if I can get rid of the property "Key" string.

Please note that the values are stored in the database.
So I don't want to hard code Key properties and et al.

UPDATE: The class structure is as follows:

```
[JsonObject(Title = "library")]
    public class CodeLibrary : IdentityBase
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is class structure?

Comment: @Dnyanesh Here it is...

Comment: Your "expected" JSON is not valid.  You can check it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BrianRogers It can be a typo. Now I have just changed. Please check. Please note that values like "new", "old" are dynamic and coming from the database. Thus I cannot hard code these... or define as fields.

Comment: @codebased So are the `old` and `new` taken from the `Key` property in your class? It's not clear from your example. Your original JSON has completely different data.